# Titanium Alloy Backbone and ACS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, backbone.js, titanium-alloy

I'm trying to pass data from Appcelerator Cloud Services to Backbone models. I couldn't find documentation on how to do this...

Below is the config from my model file:

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
        "columns": {
            "id":"integer",
            "address":"text",
            "user_completed":"integer"
        },
        "adapter": {
            "type": "", //what can I enter?
            "collection_name": "places"
        }
    },
    extendModel : function(Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            validate : function(attrs) {
                for (var key in attrs) {
                    var value = attrs[key];
                    if (value) {
                        if (key === "item") {
                            if (value.length <= 0) {
                                return 'Error: No item!';
                            }
                        }
                        if (key === "done") {
                            if (value.length <= 0) {
                                return 'Error: No completed flag!';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return Model;
    },

    extendCollection : function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
            comparator: function(places) {
                return places.get('done');
            }
        });

        return Collection;
    }
};
```

How can I pass data from ACS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use "`acs`" in your config.

Check this :

```
exports.definition = {
config: {
    "columns": {
        "id":"integer",
        "address":"text",
        "user_completed":"integer"
    },
    "adapter": {
        "type": "acs",  // Use "acs"
        "collection_name": "places"
    }
},
extendModel : function(Model) {
    _.extend(Model.prototype, {
        validate : function(attrs) {
            for (var key in attrs) {
                var value = attrs[key];
                if (value) {
                    if (key === "item") {
                        if (value.length <= 0) {
                            return 'Error: No item!';
                        }
                    }
                    if (key === "done") {
                        if (value.length <= 0) {
                            return 'Error: No completed flag!';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return Model;
},

extendCollection : function(Collection) {
    _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
        comparator: function(places) {
            return places.get('done');
        }
    });

    return Collection;
}
};
```

Check this presentation : [Titanium presentation](http://www4.uwm.edu/mobile/class/slides/tcd_training/11acs/index.html#/) under ACS topic with "**ACS in Alloy**" header.

Also , here is sample example : [Alloy backbone & ACS](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ci.alloy.acs.books)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. ACS is the name of a new sync adapter but has to be created to work. I came across the examples by aaronksaunders but the adapter seems overly complicated. Hopefully Titanium will add an ACS adapter to their next update...

Comment: Does that work for you ? If yes then please accept the answer :)